# What does it mean to add struct of different types in rust?

Tags: struct, rust, addition

I’m tyring to understand the [following code](https://github.com/Electric-Coin-Company/jubjub-prototype/blob/master/src/lib.rs#L193) which is `lc = lc + (cur, b.0)`;

And I’m getting this in gdb:

```
(gdb) pt cur
type = struct pairing::bls12_381::fr::Fr (
  pairing::bls12_381::fr::FrRepr,
)
(gdb) pt b
type = struct jubjub::Bit {
    bellman::Variable __0;
    jubjub::Assignment<bool> __1;
} *
(gdb) pt lc
type = struct bellman::LinearCombination<pairing::bls12_381::Bls12> (
  alloc::vec::Vec<(bellman::Index, pairing::bls12_381::fr::Fr)>,
)
(gdb)
```

While I know it’s about Integers, I definitely don’t understand the addition of between 3 different types. I mean that as I came from python or Java syntax, I don’t understand at all (also that it’s members who could be additionned instead of the struct itself).

Comment: There is an `impl std::ops::Add` for `LinearCombination` that takes this tuple kind defined somewhere where `LinearCombination` comes from. Implementing `std::ops::Add` allows you to write `foo + bar`.

Comment: @user2722968 yes, but what would be a definition for doing it on arbitrary types? Also, I read things incorrectly `(cur, b.0)` isn’t an addition so what does it mean?

Comment: The code `lc + (cur, b.0)` desugars to `<lc as std::ops::Add>.add((cur, b.0))`. There is an impl for `Add` where the right hand side is `(Engine::Fr, Variable)` in `bellman` [here](https://github.com/zkcrypto/bellman/blob/10c5010fd9c2ca69442dc9775ea271e286e776d8/src/lib.rs#L78).

Comment: `(cur, b.0)` is a tuple, most likely of type `(Engine::Fr, Variable)`, where `Engine::Fr` is whatever is defined via your instance of `Engine`.